# How to save in multiple table when I click save button?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save the values from my dynamic textbox in different tables at the same time. Can someone help me do this? I have 4 tables that needs to be filled. This is my tables and its fields:

**table1**
- `desk_id`
- `desk_user`
- `desk_report`
- `desk_action`

**table2**
- `print_id`
- `print_brand`
- `print_model`
- `print_report`
- `print_action`

**table3**
- `tel_id`
- `tel_local`
- `tel_user`
- `tel_report`
- `tel_action`

**table4**
- `remarks_id`
- `remarks`

My PHP code:

```
   <?php

$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","nasi") or die
('cannot connect to database error: '.mysql_error());


if (isset($_POST['desk_user']) &&
isset($_POST['desk_report']) &&
isset($_POST['desk_action']) &&
isset($_POST['print_brand']) &&
isset($_POST['print_model']) &&
isset($_POST['print_report']) &&
isset($_POST['print_action']) &&
isset($_POST['tel_local']) &&
isset($_POST['tel_user']) &&
isset($_POST['tel_report']) &&
isset($_POST['tel_action']) &&
isset($_POST['remarks']))
{

$desk_user = $_POST['desk_user'];
$desk_report = $_POST['desk_report'];
$desk_action = $_POST['desk_action'];
$print_brand = $_POST['print_brand'];
$print_model = $_POST['print_model'];
$print_report = $_POST['print_report'];
$print_action = $_POST['print_action'];
$tel_local = $_POST['tel_local'];
$tel_user = $_POST['tel_user'];
$tel_report = $_POST['tel_report'];
$tel_action = $_POST['tel_action'];
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];

if (!empty($desk_user)&& !empty($desk_report)&& !empty($desk_action) && !empty($print_brand) && !empty($print_model) && !empty($print_report) && !empty($print_action) && !empty($tel_local) && !empty($tel_user) && !empty($tel_report) && !empty($tel_action) && !empty($remarks)) {

mysql_select_db("csr", $con);
 $queries = array(); 
for($i=0; $i<count($desk_user || $print_brand || $tel_local || $remarks); $i++) 
{ 
    $queries [] = "('" .$desk_user [$i ] . "', '" .$desk_report [$i ] . "', '" .$desk_action [$i ] . "')" ;

    $queries1 [] = "( '" .$print_brand [$i ] . "', '" .$print_model [$i ] . "', '" .$print_report [$i ] . "', '" .$print_action [$i ] . "')" ;

    $queries2 [] = "('" .$tel_local [$i ] . "', '" .$tel_user [$i ] . "', '" .$tel_report [$i ] . "', '" .$tel_action [$i ] . "')" ;

    $queries3 [] = "('" .$remarks [$i ] . "')" ;
} 

if(count($queries) == 0) 
{ 
    # Nothing passed 
    # exit 
} 

$query = "insert into desktoplaptop (desk_user, desk_report, desk_action tel_local) values " . implode(", ", $queries) ; 

$query1 = "insert into printer (print_brand, print_model, print_report, print_action) values " . implode(", ", $queries1) ; 

$query2 = "insert into tel (tel_user, tel_report, tel_action) values " . implode(", ", $queries2) ;  

$query3 = "insert into remarks (remarks) values " . implode(", ", $queries3) ;  

if ($sql_run = mysql_query($query) || $sql_run = mysql_query($query1) || $sql_run = mysql_query($query2) || $sql_run = mysql_query($query3)) {
                            echo 'ok.'; 
                                }
                        else {
                                    echo '*Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';

                                    }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: did you try to issue 4 `INSERT INTO` statements to your SQL server?

Comment: Yes I try it now but it seems that only the remarks is captured. the other 3 tables doesn't get value.

Comment: help me guys please.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If there are four tables, there needs to be a unique INSERT statement for each one. With the code you provided, you only name one table: **desktoplaptop**

If there actually are four unique tables as suggested by your list above, you will need to write a unique INSERT statement which refers to each table's schema.

For example:

```
$queries = array();
if(!empty($desk_user)) {
    $queries[] = "INSERT into desktop (desk_user, desk_report, desk_action) VALUES ('" . $desk_user . "', '" .$desk_report . "', '" . $desk_action . "')'";
}
```

*repeat for other 3 tables*

```
foreach($queries as $query) {
    if ($sql_run = mysql_query($query)) {
       echo 'ok.'; 
    } else {
       echo '*Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';
    }
}
```

Note that if you are taking input from a web form, you will also want to [mysql_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) each $_POST variable to prevent injection. In addition, it seems you are using the count() function incorrectly-- you are passing it a Boolean expression when it expects an array. Overall I would suggest taking another look over exactly how your code operates.

Comment: Sorry the code I uploaded is now updated. Please see the codes that I recently edited. Only the remarks table gets value while the other three tables are empty and doesn't get the values I entered.

Answer (score 0):

Do four `INSERT` as a loop?

```
$query[0] = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (...) VALUES (...)";
$query[1] = "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (...) VALUES (...)";
//etc...

foreach ($query as $x)
  {
      if ($sql_run = mysql_query($x)) {
         echo 'ok.'; 
      } else {
         echo '*Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';
      }
  }
```